# How can I toggle between Windows and Mac commands on MKDocs?

Tags: python, markdown, documentation, mkdocs

I am using [material mkdocs](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/) for my external documentation for my users. I am wondering how can I achieve this effect of toggling between different operating system commands within the documentation?

[image: screenshot of Django docs command]

I got this screenshot from: [Django Docs tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use content tabs to switch between different tabs

https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/content-tabs/#usage